Not seeing transfer fee / tax in solscan devnet
I see that the interface on solscan is slightly different between mainnet and devnet. I was hoping to check my token transfer tax within the transaction in solscan but I can't really see it working. I have been transferring tokens with phantom wallet (on devnet) and it doesn't seem to take the transfer fee away even though on the wallet it does mention that the correct amount of transfer fee tax (percentage) is displayed.
What other ways can I check token transfer is working?

Solana FM has very nice token extensions support.
Check it out.
also, mind sharing the txHash

You can try out token creator tool for spl-22 standard(mainnet/devnet both supported) on https://app.hypersol.xyz . Those provides token creation as well as metadata management/ authority management tools.
